# Audi A6 C6, Manual won't move while in gear

Tags: transmission

Vehicle: Audi A6 C6 (EU), 2005 Manual

This happened literally an hour ago, 
I was going up the freeway in my 4th gear and suddenly I heard a sort of cracking noise and I noticed that the engine was 'disconnected' from the gearbox. I put it back into third and while I was releasing the clutch, there was this rattling noise and it also wouldn't connect.

Pulled over, tried first gear and still no movement. I'm certain it's not the clutch but most likely the gearbox.

**TLDR;** Engine won't connect to the gearbox. Releasing the clutch makes a rattling noise, not too loud but audible and the higher the gear, (6 for example) rattles more and louder than first.

Any idea's on what it could be so I could order it and get it fixed this weekend?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the clutch has failed, possibly the center plate or the pressure plate. Whichever, both will need replacing along with the release bearing. If it has a Dual Mass Flywheel then you will need to replace that as well.

However, you should have this checked out as if the noise is from inside the gearbox then that may have failed, but I don't think so as, from what you say, it has failed in all gears making me suspect the clutch.

Comment: Your conclusion sounds logical. I'll reconsider the clutch!

Comment: Turns out the drive shaft actually 'broke off' at the CV-joint. The ring inside broke causing the shaft to disconnect from the join and almost lay on the ground. I assume TCS kept the car from moving as one side didn't have any resistance. I didn't really check underneath the car at the moment it happened.

Comment: @Paramone well, glad you know and lots cheaper than the clutch...